# Свойства интерфейсов С#

Tags: c#, .net, интерфейс

Есть простая структура:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string a{ get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    class TestClass : IFoo
    {
        public string a
        {
            get { return a; }
            set
            {
                if(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    a = value; //Здесь
                else
                    a = "smth";
            }
        }
        public TestClass(string str)
        {
            a = str;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo qu = new TestClass("lol");
        Console.WriteLine(qu.a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

На сколько я знаю, у интерфейсов не должно быть полей, но свойства разрешены. Всё же, вызов сетера(в в строке "Здесь" ) кидает StackOverflow. Вопрос: почему?

Comment: Твой сеттер присваивает значение проперти, которая в свою очередь снова взывает сеттер и пытается сделать тоже самое.

Comment: Тебе либо нужно объявить приватную переменную и ссылаться на нее и приравнивать , либо оставить дефолтную реализацию интерфейса.

Comment: @adrug Но суть интерфейсов  именно в возможности переопределения поведения

Comment: Также если вам требуется такая примитивная реализация проперти, то лучше оставить вариант реализации интерфейса по умолчанию. Потому что   эта короткая запись все равно развернется в то что пытаетесь написать вы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отметках "Здесь"

```
        set
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
                a = value; //Здесь
            else
                a = "smth"; //Здесь
        }
```

Вы рекурсивно вызываете сеттер поля, потому у вас получается бесконечная рекурсия и программа падает с переполнением стека. 
Чтобы такого избежать, вы можете добавить дополнительное поле, например так

```
    private string _a;
    public string a
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
                _a = value; //Здесь
            else
                _a = "smth"; //Здесь
        }
    }
```

Интерфейсы к вашему вопросу не имеют абсолютно никакого отношения.